# Django How to get the value from many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a product update form where I want to update the sizes of a product, with a many-to-many column relation.

I am able to get the saved values but I can't get item ID or size.

{{item.id}} shows empty value.

```
{% for item in form.size.value %}
   <span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="size" id="{{ item.id }}" value="{{ item.id }}">
      <label for="{{  item.id  }}">{{ item }}</label>
   </span>
{% endfor %}
```

SIZE MODEL

```
class Size(models.Model):    
    identifier = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)    
    size = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)    
    date_created = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Date Created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Last Updated', auto_now=True)
```

PRODUCT MODEL

```
class Product(models.Model):
    identifier = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    showcased = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recommended = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)    
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2, null=True, blank=True)
    pagetitle = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    shortDescription = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)    
    longDescription = HTMLField(null=True, blank=True)
    specifications = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    features = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    care = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    subCategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory,  null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    image = models.ManyToManyField(Image, blank=True)
    size = models.ManyToManyField(Size, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    date_created = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Date Created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Last Updated', auto_now=True)
```

I have tried different ways but not had success in getting the name or  id

```
def updateProduct(request, pk):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    sizes = Size.objects.all()
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    subCategories = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=product.category.id)
    
    
    
    images = product.image.all()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('product-panel')

    form = ProductForm(instance=product)    
    return render(request, 'public/views/backend/product-update.html', {'categories':categories,'subCategories':subCategories, 'sizes':sizes, 'tags':tags, 'form':form, 'images':images})
```

Comment: Can you share the form and the view that calls the html template?

Comment: @AjayLingayat Please review the question.